# Create an IAM role / group with access to specific Cloud Storage bucket(s)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

My goal is to have a security policy that I can attach to *multiple users or service accounts* granting read access to a specific GCS bucket. So far, I was only able to either:

1. Create an IAM role that has wide read permissions on all GCS buckets and attach that to each service account / user I create (not what I want, as it grants too broad permissions)

or:

2. From the GCS bucket, grant specific read access to each user / service account as I create them (not what I want, because it is manual and error prone, and there's no decoupling, e.g. if I want to change the access level or the bucket name I will have to do it to all users).

What I'd really like is to have the ability to create a role that limits access to specific bucket(s), or have some kind of notion of "group" that I can add both users and service accounts to, and give that entire group read permission to a bucket.

This is quite easy to do in AWS IAM using groups or roles. But from what I can tell, GCP Roles are a bit different, and GCP groups are really groups of email addresses. While I suppose I can use groups for this, it feels very clunky and not the right way to achieve this.

So my question is, is there a way to create a list of service accounts / users, and give them limited permissions to specific resources (namely a GCS bucket), without having to manually manage each member?

I have seen the answer in [Google Cloud Platform creating custom IAM role and limiting access to a storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641915/google-cloud-platform-creating-custom-iam-role-and-limiting-access-to-a-storage) but this is not what I'm looking for, as this is what I suggested above in #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is to create a group and to grant permissions on this group. Then, in this group, you can add user accounts and service accounts, right?

If so, use [Groups API](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/groups). You can grand permission on this group on the resource that you want and with the correct roles.

Then you can add email in this group: User accounts have email, but also the service accounts.

So you can automate all with API call and without manual actions.

Comment: This works, thanks, and I suppose it may be the best option, it just feels weird because groups do not feel native to IAM specifically. I find it strange that in GCP you can't have fine-grained resource level control in roles, e.g. to have something like "ImageViewer" role which only has access to a specific GCS bucket with some images. But I guess it is what it is...

Comment: Is there a way to create such access control on the OBJECTS in bucket (csv files). for example I want only the person who uploaded a csv file in bucket should have access to ONLY that file he uploaded into bucket and not any other files..

Comment: In the bucket, you can use [ACL on the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists), but it's not recommend because it's difficult to monitor and to audit.